# Having a Swift class act as both a UIViewController subclass and a UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, protocols

I have been writing an app in Swift, and as a result, need to write a class that both subclasses `UIViewController` and conforms to multiple protocols (including `UIAlertViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDelegate`, and `UITableViewDataSource`). I am currently using the Xcode 6 Beta, and have come across a lot of difficulty.

The problem I'm experiencing stems from the class declaration:

```
class TableAddition :  UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate  {
```

It appears that the compiler isn't recognizing the protocol, and when I try to implement the following method:

```
@optional func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

}
```

I get an error saying "'optional' attribute can only be applied to protocol members". Although removing the `@optional` silences the error, I don't believe that the method is recognized as a member of the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol (Xcode never autocompleted the method implementation for me).

Is this a problem originating on the Swift side of things, or is this an error on my part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ["Protocols"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) in the Swift Book:

> **Optional Protocol Requirements**
>
> You can define optional requirements for protocols, These requirements
>   do not have to be implemented by types that conform to the protocol.
>   Optional requirements are prefixed by the `@optional` keyword as part of
>   the protocol’s definition.

So the `@optional` keyword is used only in the *protocol definition* to mark
optional requirements. It is not used with *implementations* of the protocol methods.
Removing `@optional` in your code is therefore the right solution.

That Xcode does not autocomplete protocol methods seems to a problem of the current
beta release.